# Input Capture mapping using PPS

Tags: input, configuration, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am trying to configure input capture module (IC1) on dsPIC33EP32MC204 to use it for duty cycle measurement. As input I would like to use RP35 pin. To test the correctness of the configuration I set up an experiment: I connected a pulse generator with 1Hz PWM pulses and set up the input capture to capture every rising edge. I reckoned that these rising edges will trigger the input capture interrupt and each call of the interrupt will cause the LED to blink. Unfortunatelly it is not working. I would be grateful if someone could tell me where is the problem. The code:

```
void Init_InputCapture(void)
{
    IC1CON1bits.ICSIDL = 0;
    IC1CON1bits.ICTSEL = 0b111;    // Peripheral clock (FP) is the clock source of the ICx
    IC1CON1bits.ICI = 0b00;        // 
    IC1CON1bits.ICM = 0b011;       //Capture mode every edge rising 
    IC1CON2bits.ICTRIG = 0;        // = Input source used to trigger the input capture timer (Trigger mode)
    IC1CON2bits.SYNCSEL = 0b00000; //IC1 module synchronizes or triggers ICx
    IC1CON2bits.IC32 = 0; // 16 bit mode only

    // Enable Capture Interrupt And Timer2
    IPC0bits.IC1IP = 1; // Setup IC1 interrupt priority level
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0; // Clear IC1 Interrupt Status Flag
    IEC0bits.IC1IE = 1; // Enable IC1 interrupt 
}
```

The interrupt:

```
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _IC1Interrupt(void)
{
    LATBbits.LATB9 = ~LATBbits.LATB9;
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0; 
}
```

And the related code from the main():

```
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & ~(1<<6));
RPINR7 = 0x23; ;    // IC1 mapped to RP35
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | (1<<6));
```

During the setup I followed the instuctions from the family reference manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted could be more complete. For dsPIC controllers it is essential to show exactly how all of the configuration bits are set and how the system clock is initialized.

This is your code corrected with the minimum required setup code:

```
/*
 * file: main.c
 * target: dsPIC33EP32MC204
 * IDE: MPLABX v4.05
 * Compiler: XC16 v1.35
 * 
 * Description:
 *  Use Input Capture 1 module to catch a 1Hz pulse on GPIO RP35 and toggle LED on RB9.
 *
 */

#pragma config ICS = PGD2               // ICD Communication Channel Select bits (Communicate on PGEC2 and PGED2)
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF             // JTAG Enable bit (JTAG is disabled)
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF            // Alternate I2C1 pins (I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins)
#pragma config ALTI2C2 = OFF            // Alternate I2C2 pins (I2C2 mapped to SDA2/SCL2 pins)
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25           // Watchdog Window Select bits (WDT Window is 25% of WDT period)
#pragma config WDTPOST = PS32768        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler bits (1:32,768)
#pragma config WDTPRE = PR128           // Watchdog Timer Prescaler bit (1:128)
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON              // PLL Lock Enable bit (Clock switch to PLL source will wait until the PLL lock signal is valid.)
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit (Watchdog Timer in Non-Window mode)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (Watchdog timer enabled/disabled by user software)
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE            // Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits (Primary Oscillator disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // OSC2 Pin Function bit (OSC2 is clock output)
#pragma config IOL1WAY = OFF            // Peripheral pin select configuration (Allow multiple reconfigurations)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD           // Clock Switching Mode bits (Clock switching is enabled,Fail-safe Clock Monitor is disabled)
#pragma config FNOSC = FRC              // Oscillator Source Selection (Internal Fast RC (FRC))
#pragma config PWMLOCK = ON             // PWM Lock Enable bit (Certain PWM registers may only be written after key sequence)
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit (Start up with user-selected oscillator source)
#pragma config GWRP = OFF               // General Segment Write-Protect bit (General Segment may be written)
#pragma config GCP = OFF                // General Segment Code-Protect bit (General Segment Code protect is Disabled)

#include <xc.h>

/* Setup the clock to run at about 60 MIPS */
#define FOSC  (7372800L)    /* nominal fast RC frequency */
#define PLL_N1 (2L)         /* PLLPRE  CLKDIV<4:0> range 2 to 33 */
#define PLL_M  (65L)        /* PLLDIV  PLLFBD<8:0> range 2 to 513 */
#define PLL_N2 (2L)         /* PLLPOST CLKDIV<7:6> range 2, 4 or 8 */
#define FSYS (FOSC*PLL_M/(PLL_N1*PLL_N2))
#define FCYC (FSYS/2L)
/*
 * Global constant data
 */
const unsigned long gInstructionCyclesPerSecond = FCYC;
/*
 * Initialize this PIC
 */
void PIC_Init( void )
{
    unsigned int ClockSwitchTimeout;

    /*
    ** Disable all interrupt sources
    */
    __builtin_disi(0x3FFF); /* disable interrupts for 16383 cycles */
    IEC0 = 0;
    IEC1 = 0;
    IEC2 = 0;
    IEC3 = 0;
    IEC4 = 0;
    IEC5 = 0;
    IEC6 = 0;
    IEC8 = 0;
    IEC9 = 0;
    __builtin_disi(0x0000); /* enable interrupts */

    CLKDIV = 0;             /* Disable DOZE mode */

    if(!OSCCONbits.CLKLOCK) /* if primary oscillator switching is unlocked */
    {
        /* Select primary oscillator as FRC */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0b000);

        /* Request switch primary to new selection */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | (1 << _OSCCON_OSWEN_POSITION));

        /* wait, with timeout, for clock switch to complete */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=10000; --ClockSwitchTimeout && OSCCONbits.OSWEN;);

        /* Configure PLL prescaler, PLL postscaler, PLL divisor */
        PLLFBD=PLL_M-2; /* M=65 */
#if   PLL_N2==2
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0; /* N2=2 */
#elif PLL_N2==4
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=1; /* N2=4 */
#elif PLL_N2==8
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=3; /* N2=8 */
#else
#error invalid PLL_N2 paramenter
#endif
        CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=PLL_N1-2; /* N1=2 */

        /* Select primary oscillator as FRCPLL */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONH(0b001);
        /* Request switch primary to new selection */
        __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | (1 << _OSCCON_OSWEN_POSITION));

        /* wait, with timeout, for clock switch to complete */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=10000; --ClockSwitchTimeout && OSCCONbits.OSWEN;);

        /* wait, with timeout, for the PLL to lock */
        for(ClockSwitchTimeout=10000; --ClockSwitchTimeout && !OSCCONbits.LOCK;);

        /* at this point the system oscillator should be 119.808MHz */
    }

    /* make all inputs digital I/O */
    ANSELA = 0x00;
    ANSELB = 0x00;
    ANSELC = 0x00;

    /* Unlock PPS Registers */ 
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & ~(_OSCCON_IOLOCK_MASK));

    /* map all PPS pins */
    RPINR7bits.IC1R = 35;    // Select RP35 (RB3/PGED1) as input for IC1

    /* Lock PPS Registers */
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON |  (_OSCCON_IOLOCK_MASK));
}
/*
 * Initialize Input Capture 1
 */
void Init_InputCapture( void )
{
    IC1CON1bits.ICSIDL = 0;
    IC1CON1bits.ICTSEL = 0b111;     // Peripheral clock (FP) is the clock source of the ICx
    IC1CON1bits.ICI = 0b00;         // 
    IC1CON1bits.ICM = 0b011;        //Capture mode every edge rising 
    IC1CON2bits.ICTRIG = 0;         // = Input source used to trigger the input capture timer (Trigger mode)
    IC1CON2bits.SYNCSEL = 0b00000;  //IC1 module synchronizes or triggers ICx
    IC1CON2bits.IC32 = 0;           // 16 bit mode only

    // Enable Capture Interrupt And Timer2
    IPC0bits.IC1IP = 4;             // Setup IC1 interrupt priority level
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0;             // Clear IC1 Interrupt Status Flag
    IEC0bits.IC1IE = 1;             // Enable IC1 interrupt 
}
/*
 * Interrupt Service Routine for IC1 
 */
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _IC1Interrupt(void)
{
    IFS0bits.IC1IF = 0; 
    LATBbits.LATB9 ^= 1;  // toggle LED
}
/*
 * Main process loop
 */
int main( void )
{
    PIC_Init();

    TRISBbits.TRISB9 = 0; // make RB9 an output
    LATBbits.LATB9 = 0;   // turn off LED

    Init_InputCapture();   

    for(;;)
    {
        /* process loop */
    }
    return 0;
}
```